# En una aplicación GX SD/Offline, no puedo hacer que un registro se elimine del Dispositivo al dejar de cumplir con la condición de carga?

Tags: genexus

Estoy usando el *How To* para hacer "mi primer aplicación SD" y luego el de "mi primer aplicación Offline".
En mis pruebas, lo que hice en la `BD Offline` es poner la condición `CompanyId=1`
En la BD `central` tengo 2 compañías. 
Originalmente, tengo un `Customer X`, con el `CompanyId=1`, se sincroniza perfectamente.
Luego, cambio en la Web el `CompanyId` de ese `Customer` a 2. Desde ahí ese registro no se actualiza en el dispositivo.
Si vuelvo a ponerlo en `CompanyId = 1` y por ejemplo, cambio el nombre, el cambio se refleja sin problemas.
Espero que se entienda el problema.

Comment: Si ese registro llegó al dispositivo a través de la sincronización, entonces cuando deja de cumplir la condición, la próxima vez que sincronice lo tiene que borrar.
Si no es así, ¿podrías copiar el log de la primer sincronización (la que trae el registro la primera vez) y el de la siguiente (la que lo debería estar borrando)?

Comment: Como consigo el log? Soy 100% nuevo... por eso estoy haciendo estos ensayos...

Comment: @MarcosCrispino, Con el adb logcat me queda un log enorme. 
Lo _filtro_ (grep)? Que _parte_? 
Todo lo que diga : **GeneXusApplication** ???

Comment: Lo que precisamos es ver qué devuelve el servicio de replicación (`<MainName>OfflienDatabase`). Podés buscar el log donde llama a ese servicio, o si el log es muy grande capaz que usar Fiddler o TcpTrace para ver solo las llamadas al servidor.

Comment: @MarcosCrispino, No consigo hacer el log... sorry, pero el fiddler no me muestra las trazas del puerto 8080... No veo como configurarlo para que muestre el tráfico del Tomcat y la verdad, estoy corto de tiempo para buscar ... Hay algún doc para ir directo?